# Error thrown on changing the alpha property

Tags: android, layout, transparency, alpha

I get this error for setting the alpha property to a view

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.View.setAlpha
```

in my code

```
((View) findViewById(R.id.view)).setAlpha(100);

//with float value also doesn't works
```

What might be the problem ? I do not have any compile errors just on runtime

Comment: setAlpha() was not there before version 3.0..which is ur version??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29) states, `setAlpha` requires API 11. You probably have your minSDK set to something below 11 and are installing/running this on a device which is below 11. That means it doesn't have this method, so Java can't find it.

Comment: tnx, I always forget to see the api level :(

Answer (score 1):

I used code to setAlpha of the image itself, not the view. This is available from API level 1..

```
public void toggleButton(int i) {
    if (indImageBtnEnabled[i]) {

        int di = getDrawableId(findViewById(myImagebtns[i]));
        Drawable d = this.getResources().getDrawable(di);
        d.setAlpha(25);

        ((ImageView) findViewById(myImagebtns[i])).setImageDrawable(d);

        indImageBtnEnabled[i] = false;
    } else {
        // findViewById(myImagebtns[i]).setAlpha(1f) << NEEDS API11;
        int di = getDrawableId(findViewById(myImagebtns[i]));
        Drawable d = this.getResources().getDrawable(di);
        d.setAlpha(255);

        ((ImageView) findViewById(myImagebtns[i])).setImageDrawable(d);

        indImageBtnEnabled[i] = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **setAlpha()** This method was deprecated in API level 16.
>
> use **setImageAlpha(int)** instead

probably you have an android:targetSdkVersion higher than 15, so you can validate when use setAlpha or

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1) {
    ((View) findViewById(R.id.view)).setImageAlpha(100);
    } else {
    ((View) findViewById(R.id.view)).setAlpha(100);
}
```

the value of `Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH_MR1` is  15